# JS hide div if it has a class added via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, class

I am working on a code where an `active` class is added to a div via JS.

What I would like to do is, when that div has `active` class, hide another div. But, due to the `active` class was added via JS, this code doesn't work:

```
if($("#section3").hasClass("active")) {
    $(".menu").fadeOut("fast");
}
```

I think I would need to use the on function: [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Something like this, but it's not working... Any ideas?

```
$("#section3").on( function() {
    $(this).hasClass('active') {
        $(".menu").fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

EDITED:

I'm afraid I cannot paste the code because I am using a plugin. [This is the one that I am using](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scrolloverflow-reset.html#secondPage), so you can see the functionality there.

I've added this bullet menu to it:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="slide1"><a href="#slide1"><span></span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="slide2"><a href="#slide2"><span></span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="slide3"><a href="#slide3"><span></span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="slide4"><a href="#slide4"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Each slide has a `active class` when it's on viewport, so what I would like to achieve is when the last slider is active, hide the menu

Comment: Just hide another div in function where you add 'active' class

Comment: add the whole code where you add class by js

Comment: do you have multiple same id `section3`?

Comment: Put html and css please

Comment: @patie add your html and jquery so that we can check. better if you can create a fiddle link

Comment: which is the change slide event for this plugin ?

Comment: try like this:-`$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($('#menu li:last-child').hasClass('active'){
     $('#menu').hide();
  });
});`

Comment: The thing is that the #menu doesn't have a active class... is the #section the one who has it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oth the section and the li have active classes so you could use something like this or use the `afterSlideLoad` event if it is depeding of the slideshow

```
$(window).on("scroll",function() {
  if ($('#menu li:last-child').hasClass("active")) {
    ("#menu").fadeOut("fast")
  }
})
```

or you can use slideIndex to check if you are on the last slide. see here > [afterSlideLoad](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex)

Comment: i do not understand what you really want. you want when you are on the SECTION 4 from your example. to hide the menu ?

Comment: @patie are you sure about that ? in the example you gave ( https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scrolloverflow-reset.html#4thpage )  both the section and the li have active classes

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('section').click(function(){

$(this).addClass('active');
if($('section').hasClass('active')){

$('ul#menu').hide();

}
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>check</section>
<ul id="menu">
<li data-menuanchor="slide1"><a href="#slide1"><span></span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="slide2"><a href="#slide2"><span></span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="slide3"><a href="#slide3"><span></span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="slide4"><a href="#slide4"><span></span></a></li>


</ul>
```